# can I open PhotoGallery using 'DKImagePickerController' in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, photo-gallery

I want to open PhotoGallery in iPad using 'DKImagePickerController', is it possible??

I have tried to open gallery using UIImagePickerController and its work fine but i have only one option(popoverPresentationController) to open Gallery and its seems small screen to select photo.

```
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
```

I want to open only PhotoGallery in landscape mode.

Comment: DKImagePickerController is a swift library, it should be available for swift.

Comment: but how can i open Library using DKImagePickerController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()

 pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
print("didSelectAssets")
print(assets)
}

self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true)
```

use this code to open the camera